# Nagio NRPE - Always return 0

Tags: bash, nagios, nrpe

I'm trying to execute a bash script in nagios by using nrpe client, but it is always returning "0" value as output.

If i'm using this command in the script:

> _VAR=$(atop -r file.atop | grep '^DSK' | tr -s ' ' | grep "sda" | cut -d '|' -f 3 | grep -o '[0-9]+')
>
> echo $_VAR

Then - everything is working properly and on the server i'm receiving correct value by running

> /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H X.X.X.X-c
>   check_asterisk_extensions

But, if i'm changing the command to:

> _VAR=$(/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx 'sip show peers' | grep -i 'ok' | wc -l)
>
> echo $_VAR

Then, on the server, I'm receiving permanently "0".

Locally both scripts are returning correct values.

I've tried also by using a php script which converts the variable to the integer:

> $strCommand="/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx 'sip show peers' | grep -i 'ok' |
>   wc -l";
>   //$strCommand="atop -r file.atop | grep '^DSK' | tr -s ' ' | grep "sda" | cut -d '|' -f 3 | grep -o '[0-9]+'";
>
> $string=shell_exec("$strCommand");
>
> $str = (int) "$string"; echo $str;

But, result is the same: With the first command is not working - with the second - all good.

Could someone can explain why is this happening?

Comment: Have you ran `/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx 'sip show peers'`manually and checked if the output is what you expect?

Comment: Yes, if I'm running the script manually - everything is working fine.

Comment: Any environment variables that aren't set correctly whan it is run by nagios?

Comment: No, all environment variables are default, and are the same for both commands.

Comment: What is also interesting, if I'm sending output to the file, and then getting it from there with "cat" - then I'm receiving the correct output.

Comment: The user which exrcutes nrpe on your asterisk has rights to execute /usr/sbin/asterisk ? You can test if you open a shell locally with nagios user

Answer (score 0):

It was very simple, nagios user didn't have permission to execute command asterisk -rx. Changing command to "sudo asterisk -rx" solved this issue.